# custom feature function with (python) crfsuite

Tags: python, crf, python-crfsuite

I have only read theorey about CRF so far and want to use python crfsuite in my master thesis for extracting ingredients from recipes. Every help is appreciated.

As far as I understand, I can provide training data to crfsuite in the form of the picture below, where w[0] provides the identity of the current word, w[i] the world relative to i and pos[i] its part-of-speech-tag relative to i.

[image: training data format]

And then crfsuite trains its own feature functions build on the given attributes.

But I can't find a way for providing custom feature functions like "w[i] is in a dictionary" (for example a dictionary of recipe ingredients) or "in the sentence is a negation" (for example "not", or "don't").

In general good tutorials are appreciated, because the manuals (https://python-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/manual.html) are not beginner-friendly from my point of view

Answer (score 2):

With [python-crfsuite](https://github.com/tpeng/python-crfsuite) (or [sklearn-crfsuite](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite)) training data doesn't have to be in the form you've described; a single training sequence should be a list of `{"feature_name": <feature_value>"}` dicts, with features for each sequence elements (e.g. for a token in a sentence). Features don't have to be words or POS tags. There is a few other supported feature formats (see http://python-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest).

For a more complete example check https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite/blob/master/docs/CoNLL2002.ipynb - it uses custom features.

Comment: I understand now, that a feature function can be implemented through additional labels. For example when the feature function is starts-with-upper-case I could add to each word a lebel UPPER_CASE or NOT_UPPER_CASE

From my point of view the documentation is not so good. After reading the theory I expected to overwrite some functions. This label trick is smart, because it is independent of any programming language, but was to smart for me as beginner...^^